Understanding least upper bound under Dedekind cuts
I'm studying real numbers under Dedekind's cuts construction ($x=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}:x<q \text{ for some } q\in\mathbb{Q\}}$ would be a real number).
The theorem I'm trying to understand is this: for any $\varnothing \neq A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $\min (\uparrow A)$ exists.
My book says that the candidate for $\min (\uparrow A)= \bigcup A$. That would mean that (for example) $\bigcup[0,1) = 1$ but why is it the case?
When I see finite unions of reals I can see the union is the maximum of the system, for example $\bigcup\{1,2,3\} = 3$ because of Dedekind's cut definition. So I can se that $\cup A \in A$. But what happen in infinite case (infinite refering to the cardinal of the set system in which I'm applying union) that it's not the case? ($\bigcup[0,1)$ as I mentioned above) Why $1=\cup [0,1] \in [0,1]$ even if $[0,1]$ is also infinite? Thanks in advance

Can you define that up arrow notation? Also those cuts you describe at the tope only correspond to rational numbers. You don’t get all reals (or any) with that scheme.

Convince yourself that $\bigcup [0, 1)$ is the Dedekind cut defined by $x < 1$, hence represents the real number $1$.

It can sometimes help to see this as a Zeno's Paradox of the Arrow: $\bigcup [0,1) = {0} \cup [1/2,1) = \bigcup {0,1/2} \cup \bigcup [3/4,1) = \cdots $.  The interesting thing is only what's happening near $1$.  So, can you specify a rational number less than one that is not in any of the $[1-1/2^n,1)$?

I have suppressed tag "number systems" which refers for example to base-n representations...
